# Yii2: authclient

Tags: php, yii2, facebook-login, yii2-advanced-app

I've used [Yii 2 authclient](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient)  in my app and when i try it , it gives me

> Unknown component ID: authClientCollection

the code i used in config\main.php

```
 'facebook' => [
        'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
        'authUrl' => 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup',
        'clientId' => ' my app id from facebook', 
        'clientSecret' => 'My App Secret',
    ],
```

in login page :

```
 <?= yii\authclient\widgets\authChoice::widget(['baseAuthUrl'=>['site/auth']]) ?>
```

any help please .

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap this configuration in

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
        // add your facebook config here
    ],
],
```

which is [CLEARLY stated in documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/docs/guide/installation.md#configuring-application).

Comment: it work ,, but when i try the login buttons it give me `Class yii\authClient\authAction does not exist` .

Comment: This is different issue and it is also described in the guide

Answer (score 0):

Try like so,

```
'facebook' => [
            'class' => yii\authclient\clients\Facebook::class,
            'clientId' => 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID',
            'clientSecret' => 'YOUR_FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET',
            'scope' => 'email,public_profile',
            'attributeNames' => [
                'name',
                'email',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
            ]
        ]
```